# cannot send email using office 365 credentials using C#

Tags: c#, .net, email, office365

I am trying to send email with my office 365 credentials using C#. But It is failing to send and getting exception.

How to fix this? Is it possible to send from office 365?

```
     foreach (var filename in files)
     {
           String userName = "sri@MyOffice365domain.com";
           String password = "password";
           MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
           SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com");
           mail.From = new MailAddress("sri@MyOffice365domain.com");
           mail.To.Add("senderaddress@senderdomain.com");
           mail.Subject = "Fwd: for " + filename;
           mail.Body = "mail with attachment";

           System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
           attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(filename);
           mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

           SmtpServer.Port = 587;
           SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password);
           SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

           SmtpServer.Send(mail);
}
```

> Transaction failed. The server response was: 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message.

Comment: Is this `sri@MyOffice365domain.com` hosted on Office 365 online tenant?

Comment: yes. I have Office 365 online account.

Answer (score 0):

How many emails are you going to send simultaneously?

> foreach (var filename in files)

All Outlook APIs accessed via `https://outlook.office.com/api` or `https://outlook.office365.com/api` have a limit is 60 requests per minute, per user (or group), per app ID. So, for now, developers only can make limited APIs calls from the app. Read through the [Microsoft Blog Post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2017/04/07/throttling-coming-to-outlook-api-and-microsoft-graph/) for more details on REST API call limitations.

Try to use the following code instead:

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("someone@somedomain.com", "SomeOne"));
msg.From = new MailAddress("you@yourdomain.com", "You");
msg.Subject = "This is a Test Mail";
msg.Body = "This is a test message using Exchange OnLine";
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("your user name", "your password");
client.Port = 587; // You can use Port 25 if 587 is blocked (mine is!)
client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.EnableSsl = true;
try
{
    client.Send(msg);
    lblText.Text = "Message Sent Succesfully";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    lblText.Text = ex.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I tried that too. `A from address must be specified.` error getting.